# APC shows me the same page when requesting totaly different page?

Tags: php, configuration, apc

I just installed APC on my local machine.

Here is my configuration (no php.ini configuration at all right now)

```
apc.cache_by_default    On
apc.canonicalize    On
apc.coredump_unmap  Off
apc.enable_cli  Off
apc.enabled On
apc.file_md5    Off
apc.file_update_protection  2
apc.filters no value
apc.gc_ttl  3600
apc.include_once_override   Off
apc.lazy_classes    Off
apc.lazy_functions  Off
apc.max_file_size   1M
apc.mmap_file_mask  no value
apc.num_files_hint  1000
apc.preload_path    no value
apc.report_autofilter   Off
apc.rfc1867 Off
apc.rfc1867_freq    0
apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix  upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600
apc.serializer  default
apc.shm_segments    1
apc.shm_size    32M
apc.slam_defense    On
apc.stat    On
apc.stat_ctime  Off
apc.ttl 0
apc.use_request_time    On
apc.user_entries_hint   4096
apc.user_ttl    0
apc.write_lock  On
```

I've a tools.dev vhost, in which I put phpinfo.php & apc.php (the provided stats frontend script)

If I request first tools.dev/phpinfo.php then If I request tools.dev/apc.php I got the phpinfo()

That's weird, and I don't understand why, I can reset the problem when I restart my server.

I'm running Zend Server, I compiled APC myself on my Mac OS X 10.6 and the extension is loaded and working.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What if you will try request apc.php first? Maybe you having fatal error on apc.php and your browser won't refresh page, because he hasn't answer from server. Sorry for my English.

Comment: And I recommend turn `apc.slam_defense` to `off` (but it doesn't relates to your current problem).

Comment: If I request apc.php I can see the APC stats page, hits, etc. However, the only cached file is : *hidden*/apc.php 15 381208 2011/05/08 15:24:34 By the way, if I try to access to a different virtualhost I also access to the apc.php file

Comment: Then I think problem can be in server (apache, nginx). Try to check their logs.

Comment: If I disable `apc.enabled` all is working properly, there are nothing wrong in my logs neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not the first one to experience this. A bug ticket was open at http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=11357 but it is now suspended for lack of feedback. Maybe you could add a note to this bug and hope a developer will help you track down the bug and fix it.